# imagepng returns null and doesn't save file on server

Tags: php, laravel, image-processing

I have a bit of a weird issue I hope you can help me out with.
I'm working on a Laravel project and have a function that reduces image size via: `imagepng` - on the local copy it works great but on the server, the image doesn't get saved to the folder (0755 permission).
This is the function:

```
public function imageReduce($file, $fullname, $unique){

    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$fullname));
    $imageName = "/pics/reduced/$unique-$file.png";
    $fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$imageName;
    imagepng($image, $fullPath, 9);
    $path['path'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$imageName;
    return $path;
}
```

I have no idea where to start looking, since as  mentioned - it works fine locally.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your error log? Do you have php-gd installed on the server?

Comment: `0755 permission` for `www-data`?

Comment: No errors, no idea what php-gd is so i'm assuming no. 0755 permission for the pics/reduced folder

Comment: You have not put a separator after `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: True. However that isn't the reason the image isn't being saved. The saving part should be within "imagepng"

Answer (score 0):

Look at $fullpath. you have a trailing '/' but $imageName also has a leading '/'.
When you concatenate, the end result is a double '//' in $fullpath.

Also - to help you debug, why not turn errors on?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```